# Single elimination tournaments with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm

So I have a `User` model and I want to create tournament brackets (single elimination) with my friends. I have 3 models:

```
Tournament
has_many :players
has_many :matches

Player
belongs_to: tournament
belongs_to: user
has_many_and_belongs_to :matches

Match
belongs_to: tournament
has_many_and_belongs_to :players
```

So what I do is I have a form when they create a Tournament and you can select friends to be part of it.

I create the `Tournament` object, then create the `Player` objects, and then finally create the `Match` objects. The `match_player` table has data like round number and player scores.

Is this a good way to approach it? Or is there an easier way that I'm not seeing? I just feel like this is quite a crude approach to the problem.

Comment: Just move `round_number` from `match_player` table to the `matches` one. When Round has more specific attributes (than number), you could create `Round` which belongs to `Tournament` and switch `Match` to belongs to `Round`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a match player which specifying a user appearing certain match, instead you can use the player itself as the avathar connecting user to match and hold info like current round. Also no need of redundant player id in tournament which varies the normalization rails prefer, since you can get players from tournament by tournament.matches.joins :players

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.